# JFrame.setBackground(Color) modify a ImageIcon size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I start Java from few days and I just start to deal with swing and **AWT**.
I am trying to make **pop a transparent animated GIF** and place my windows to a specific location. The problem is that I can't put it in the right-bottom corner of my screen. So, I try few things (*make the window full screen and move the JLabel compoment in, move the window with setBounds, …*) but I just realized that if I delete the

```
this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

I lose ***transparency***, but my picture also change **size** and is at the good place.

**Code :**

---

```
public class Fenetre extends JFrame {
    private static final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    private static final int screen_width = (int) screenSize.width;
    private static final int screen_height = (int) screenSize.height;

    URL url;                //Get the source URL
    Icon icon;              //For animated gif support
    JLabel label;           //Contain the picture

    /**** CONSTRUCTOR ****/
    public Fenetre(String pUrl,String name) throws MalformedURLException{
        url = new URL(pUrl);

        icon = new ImageIcon(url);
        label = new JLabel(icon);

        this.add(label);
        this.setTitle(name);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));  

        this.pack();
        this.setLocation(screen_width-label.getWidth(),screen_height-label.getHeight());
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I instantiate my class fenetre in my main.

Thanks for the help :)

**EDIT :**
I reformulate :
I will see later for a more proper way to get size of the screen (this work for now).
I just have this :
[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP2qh.png)

Here I launch it twice: one with the `this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` and one witout. We can clairly see that the one witout is more larger and fit with the screen (where the one with dont).

What i want is to have the transparency witout this image resizing.

Comment: Don't use `label.getWidth()`, use `this.getWidth()` instead, also `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();` won't deal with other inset elements, like the task bar

Comment: I already try with : `this.getWidth()` and `icon.getIconWidth()` to but thats produce the same result. The problem is that (I think) the *picture is resize* by `this.setBackground(color)` And the JLabel isn't resize and keep the original picture size. Don't know why nor how.

Comment: *"(I think) the picture is resize by this.setBackground(color)"* - Doesn't effect the the size of the window, since you call `pack` the window would be resize after it anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% I understand your particular problem, but, I would avoid using `private static final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();` as a determination of the screen size, as it doesn't take into account things like OS elements like the task bar and dock.

The following example simply displays a red square at the bottom/right side the screen, avoiding things like the task bar and dock

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));  
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                Rectangle bounds = getScreenBounds();
                int x = bounds.x + (bounds.width - frame.getWidth());
                int y = bounds.y + (bounds.height - frame.getHeight());
                frame.setLocation(x, y);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static Rectangle getScreenBounds() {
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
        bounds = gc.getBounds();

        Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc);

        bounds.x += insets.left;
        bounds.y += insets.top;
        bounds.width -= (insets.right + insets.left);
        bounds.height -= (insets.bottom + insets.top);
        return bounds;
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

    }

}
```

## Updated

I modify the `TestPane` to include a label showing the size of the component...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private JLabel label;

    public TestPane() {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        label = new JLabel("...");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate();
        label.setText(getWidth() + "x" + getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

}
```

Run it with and without calling `frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` and saw no difference

Comment: So its may be me but in your exemple the red square dont fit with the screen border, anyway what I use work for non-transparent gif (and is quite more simple :) ).

Comment: I confirm that i have exactly the same problem, the size of the red sqare change if i delete the `setBackground` property (he get more larger).

Comment: What OS? What Java version?

Comment: *"he red square dont fit with the screen border,"* - I've updated the calculations - thought they were wrong

Comment: So, I have windows 10 with Java 9.0.4
I try the same code in a windows 10 virtual machine and java 10.0.1 and its work. I am pretty lost where :I

Answer (score 0):

Seems that install the last java JDK Dev Kit solve the problem. If someone know why this append with the 9.0.4 JRE I am pretty much interest.